# How to Fix http: "panic serving 127.0.0.1:54063: 403 Forbidden: Forbidden"

Tags: go

The error as can be seen is the 403 Forbidden being returned by the client.GetKeyStats function.

Based on the source code no need to authenticate. 
sourcecode: https://github.com/timpalpant/go-iex 
"The reason you're getting a panic is due to raising a panic directly in this function.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/timpalpant/go-iex"
  "html/template"
  "net/http"
)

func process(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  client := iex.NewClient(&http.Client{})
  symbols := []string{"AAPL", "SPY"}
  stat, err := client.GetKeyStats(symb)

  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  var s []string

  for _, symb := range symbols {

    s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("DividendYield: %s", stat.DividendYield))
  }

  t, _ := template.ParseFiles("Dividends.html")
  t.Execute(w, s)

}

func main() {

  server := http.Server{
    Addr: "127.0.0.1:8080",
  }
  http.HandleFunc("/process", process)
  server.ListenAndServe()

}
```

The error as can be seen is the 403 Forbidden being returned by the client.GetKeyStats function. Do you need to authenticate this client in some way?
Either way this doesn't seem like a relevant issue to Go as a language."

> 2020/01/27 03:34:59 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:54063: 403 Forbidden: Forbidden
>
> .         goroutine 19 [running]:
>                           net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc000162820)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1767 +0x139
>                           panic(0x1442140, 0xc0002defb0)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b2
>                           main.process(0x158d1e0, 0xc0001ba000, 0xc0001a8000)
>                               /Users/ed/Documents/Coding/Golang/src/web/web.go:18 +0x373
>                           net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x150b0d0, 0x158d1e0, 0xc0001ba000, 0xc0001a8000)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2007 +0x44
>                           net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x18d3180, 0x158d1e0, 0xc0001ba000, 0xc0001a8000)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2387 +0x1bd
>                           net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001640e0, 0x158d1e0, 0xc0001ba000, 0xc0001a8000)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2802 +0xa4
>                           net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000162820, 0x158dce0, 0xc00019e000)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1890 +0x875
>                           created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2928 +0x384
>                           2020/01/27 03:34:59 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:54064: 403 Forbidden: Forbidden
>                           goroutine 20 [running]:
>                           net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0001628c0)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1767 +0x139
>                           panic(0x1442140, 0xc0003cab90)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:679 +0x1b2
>                           main.process(0x158d1e0, 0xc00022d420, 0xc0001a6000)
>                               /Users/ed/Documents/Coding/Golang/src/web/web.go:18 +0x373
>                           net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x150b0d0, 0x158d1e0, 0xc00022d420, 0xc0001a6000)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2007 +0x44
>                           net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x18d3180, 0x158d1e0, 0xc00022d420, 0xc0001a6000)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2387 +0x1bd
>                           net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001640e0, 0x158d1e0, 0xc00022d420, 0xc0001a6000)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2802 +0xa4
>                           net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0001628c0, 0x158dce0, 0xc0000a0340)
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1890 +0x875
>                           created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
>                               /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2928 +0x384
>                           2020/01/27 03:34:59 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:54066: 403 Forbidden: Forbidden
>                           goroutine 47 [running]:

Answer (score 0):

What you mention is indeed [`timpalpant/go-iex` issue 33](https://github.com/timpalpant/go-iex/issues/33), following [`golang/go` issue 36883](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36883)

Try first running the [`client_test.go#TestGetKeyStats()`](https://github.com/timpalpant/go-iex/blob/aef4b1ffa75e6ac49e802602137d15d6f3200685/client_test.go#L662)

> My question is to see if you can point me to the root cause, being the my Code or the API source

Here it is the source code, not the API: a panic within the goroutine of an Go HTTP client would generate that error message.

Answer (score 0):

The API has changed since last time the Go library was updated. Therefore, it seems it used to accept unauthenticated API request, but now, you need a token as per the documentation: https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/

> ## Authentication
>
> ### API Tokens
>
> IEX Cloud authenticates your API requests using your account’s API tokens. To use any IEX Cloud API, you must pass an API token with each request. If you do not include your API token when making an API request, or use one that is incorrect or disabled, IEX Cloud returns an error.

You’ll have to use an up to date Go library like the one suggested in the [documentation](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#client-and-server-libraries-that-support-iex-cloud)

https://github.com/goinvest/iexcloud